# Can I not provide an equality condition in a while loop?

Tags: c

I wrote this code and only 'Hello' got printed.

```
float x=1.1;
printf("Hello\n");
while(x-1.1==0)
{
   printf("%f\n",x);
   x=x-1;
}
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are not always exact.  In your case, `x` (as `float`) is not exactly equal to `1.1` (as `double`) due to lower precision and floating point types that don't use base 10 internally.

Comment: The code *does* provide an equality condition.. reconsider the [real] question.

Comment: use this... while(fabs(x-1.1)<0.000001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with floating point operations, you don't get the results as you would expect.

What you are seeing is:

1. `1.1` is represented as a `float` in `x`.
2. In the `while` statement, `1.1` is of type `double`, not `float`. Hence, `x` is promoted to a `double` before the subtraction and comparison is made.

   You lose precision in these steps. Hence `x-1.1` does not evaluate to `0.0`.

You can see expected results if you use appropriate floating point constants.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test1()
{
   printf("In test1...\n");
   float x=1.1;

   // Use a literal of type float, not double.
   if (x-1.1f == 0)
   {
      printf("true\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("false\n");
   }
}

void test2()
{
   printf("In test1...\n");

   // Use a variable of type double, not float.
   double x=1.1;
   if (x-1.1 == 0)
   {
      printf("true\n");
   }
   else
   {
      printf("false\n");
   }
}

int main()
{
   test1();
   test2();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In test1...
true
In test2...
true
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Siyual. Explained it nicely!

Answer (score 2):

This is because `x` is a single-precision floating-point number, but you subtract the constant `1.1` from it, which is double-precision.  So your single-precision `1.1` is converted to double-precision, and the subtraction is performed, but the result is non-zero (since `1.1` cannot be exactly represented, but the double-precision value is closer than the single-precision value).  Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float x = 1.1;
    double y = 1.1;

    printf("%.20g\n", x - 1.1);
    printf("%.20g\n", y - 1.1);

    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, the result is:

```
2.384185782133840803e-08
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare float like -0.000001 < x - 1.1 && x - 1.1 < 0.00001

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on floating point precision.

TL;DR is - x-1.1 is not really round 0.

for example, in my debugger, x equals to 1.10000002 - this is due to the nature of the floating point precision.

Relevant read:

http://floating-point-gui.de/